# Find a RegEx for special characters

Tags: php, regex

I have this URL

```
{{ url:sites }}/files/large/49a076e0c8244c458b2ff9ca3a25a811.jpg
```

and I need to get this URL:

```
/files/large/49a076e0c8244c458b2ff9ca3a25a811.jpg
```

I have tried multiple regex and apart from causing errors none have worked.

Here are some that I have tried

```
$thumbImage = preg_replace("/^[url\:site]/", '', $movingImageThumb); // this works but doesn't remove {{ }}

$thumbImage = preg_replace("/[\{\{url\:site\}\}]/", '', $movingImageThumb);//throws an error

$thumbImage = preg_replace("/[{{url\:site}}]/", '', $movingImageThumb);// throws an error
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I would guess you are having escaping issues in whatever language youy are using.  `{` and `}` have regexp special meaning

Comment: Can't you use a simple `str_replace()`?

Answer (score 1):

If your string to remove is constant, you could just do:

```
$out = str_replace("{{ url:sites }}","",$url);
```

Or, if there's even the slightest change that your search term might appear in the target string as well:

```
$out = substr($url,strlen("{{ url:sites }}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is a character class, whatever you place inside that class are considered to match one character from any of those characters.

Try any of these two example for you:

```
$url2 = preg_replace('~.*?(?=/files)~', '', $url);
print "$url2\n";
```

and,

```
$url3 = preg_replace('~\{\{ url:sites \}\}~', '', $url);
print "$url3\n";
```

Comment: Not seen `~` used before - is that a PHP specific RegEx character?

Comment: @freefaller Any non-alphanumeric and non-whitespace character may be used as a delimiter. Personally, I use parentheses because they come in matching pairs and therefore never need escaping, no matter what the regex.

Comment: @Niet, you learn something new every day, if you're not careful ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it would probably be like this:

```
$url = "{{ url:sites }}/files/large/49a076e0c8244c458b2ff9ca3a25a811.jpg";
print preg_replace('%\{\{.*?\}\}%', '', $url);
```

You have to escape the `{` and `}`'s because they otherwise have special meaning in a regex. `.*` matches everything between the `{{` and `}}` and the `?` makes it non-greedy, so in case you have two `{{ ... }}` sets, it won't start with the first `{{` and end with the last `}}`.

For example:

```
{{ url:sites }}/bla/bla/{{ path:somewhere }}
```

If you woudn't use the `?` it would replace all of it (between the first `{{` and the last `}}`). But with the `?` it will replace the separate `{{ ... }}` sets, so you'll get:

```
/bla/bla/
```